# Creating Spring-backed actors as routees

Tags: java, spring, akka

Problem: I would like to have a thread pool allocated to a number of actors making some blocking calls (eg. to a web service, database, etc).

I have the following configuration:

```
threadpool-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    core-pool-size-min = 4
    core-pool-size-max = 8
  }
}
```

and the following setup method for my **Router** actor:

```
private final int numberOfChildren = 4;

@Override
public void preStart() throws Exception {
    log.info("Starting up.. creating {} children", numberOfChildren);
    List<Routee> routees = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; i++) {
        ActorRef actor = getContext().actorOf(springActorExtension.props(routeeClass)
                                .withDispatcher(THREADPOOL_DISPATCHER));
        getContext().watch(actor);
        routees.add(new ActorRefRoutee(actor));
    }
    router = new Router(new SmallestMailboxRoutingLogic(), routees);
    super.preStart();
}
```

SpringActorExtension is similar to the code presented [here](http://kimrudolph.de/blog/spring-boot-meets-akka/), it just uses Class objects instead of names.

The routees are created by Spring in the end, for example:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public HttpClientActor httpClient() {
    return new HttpClientActor();
}
```

All this works fine, but my problem is that the number of threads that the thread pool executor is configured to use must be declared at two places:

1. in the threadpool-dispatcher configuration
2. in the code of the router (`numberOfChildren`)

Reading through the [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#Pool) there seems to be a way to create routees automatically based on the configuration alone, eg.

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /parent/router1 {
    router = round-robin-pool
    nr-of-instances = 5
  }
}
```

However, that does not say how (by whom) should the routee actors be created.

Is there a way to either

1. explain Akka to have the routees created by Spring
2. or access the `thread-pool-executor` configuration (eg. the number of threads) in the code above and remove the need for specifying the number of threads two times.